# Java language-detection returning different probabilities given the same input

Tags: java, language-detection

I'm using the Java [language-detection](https://code.google.com/p/language-detection/) library in the following way:

```
Detector detector = DetectorFactory.create(); //profiles are in the default location
detector.append("What language is this text?");
List<Language> languages = detector.getProbabilities();
Language mostProbable = languages.get(0);
System.out.println(mostProbable.lang + " - " + mostProbable.prob);
```

The `prob` value varies slightly from execution to execution given the exact same input. Is that "normal"? What does that depend on?

Comment: *"The prob value varies slightly from execution to execution"* ***How***? Show us.

Comment: What @T.J.Crowder said, show us the input and the slightly diff prob values.

Comment: The input is secret :) The results are: 0.9999945454065466, 0.9999943739537236, 0.9999949374128473, 0.9999944875939283, 0.9999945975357323, 0.9999945125325345, 0.9999944234173573, 0.9999945984572353, 0.9999945351465767, 0.9999945596853r53, and so on....

Answer (score 2):

If the algorithm / method the library is using is not deterministic then the values may vary per execution.

For example, some algorithms need to be given an initial seed to begin. In a lot of cases, this seed is (pseudo)-randomly chosen. This can affect the final output.

EDIT: It looks like that library is using Naive Bayesian Classifiers (which can probably be either or).

Comment: A quick scan over the source code appears to confirm this; line 246 of Detector.java uses random numbers to update the language probability.